# Simplifying this Swift 4 logic

Tags: swift

Complete newb to Swift 4 here. How can the following be more compactly written in Swift?

```
    if myVar != nil {

        if !myVarList.contains(myVar!) {

            myVarList.append(myVar!)
        }
    }
```

I tried searching for examples of `guard` but couldn't find anything. I think Swift allows me to more compactly deal with the `nil` checking, but not sure how to go about it when combined with the nested conditional.

Comment: You should ***really*** read [the Swift language guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `if let` to conditional unwrap the optional and do the other check in the same line, the comma represents a boolean `AND` operator

```
if let item = myVar, !myVarList.contains(item) {
   myVarList.append(item)
}
```

If an (unwrapped) optional is going to be used after the check never write `!= nil`

`guard` is only useful if an evaluation to `false` exits the scope

```
func foo() {
    guard let item = myVar, !myVarList.contains(item) else { return }
    myVarList.append(item)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. How come I don't need to write `let item = myVar!`i.e. unwrapped..

Comment: `if let` unwraps the optional on success. Please read [Swift Language Guide: Optionals](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID330)